# feeling... decreased visits?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I observed a reduction in views to questions since some week. I used to hit tens of views rather quickly, but now I hardly reach 10. This is strange, because I am mostly asking questions in java, which should be pretty popular. See for example

[how can I know if an applet is running in a browser vs. invoked from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513245/how-can-i-know-if-an-applet-is-running-in-a-browser-vs-invoked-from-eclipse) (17 views)

[How to search string under cursor in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513583/how-to-search-string-under-cursor-in-eclipse/) (18 views)

[abstract class MouseAdapter vs. interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513976/abstract-class-mouseadapter-vs-interface) (28 views)

Also the most viewed questions are around 800 views, not very high I would say.
Did something change in the site traffic? did the vote recount piss off people so much that they left ? Or maybe I am extrapolating from a too limited/biased dataset ? Also, there has been an openid outage, and depending on how visits are counted (with/without anonymous) many people could have been logged out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the way views were recorded, which made them artifically high.

This bug was fixed a few months ago.

Comment: I assume this should, in principle, affect the badges obtained so far. Not that it matters... clearly. Well, at least to me...

Comment: they weren't THAT much higher. It's also quite possible that with increased traffic each question will get fewer views, as it gets pushed off the homepage and question pages faster.

Comment: very good point. My observation was rather abrupt, so I assumed something due to a well-localized event. Increased traffic tends to be smooth, and should decrease the transit time smoothly.